# Get object count from a has many pg_search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have has_many relationship between `product` and `variation` models.  I am also using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) to help filter search results.

I need to display the total count of products from a filtered search result as well as the total count for the variations of those filtered products.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_for,
                  against: %i(name body),
                  associated_against: { variations: :name, categories: :name, tags: :name },
                  using: {
                      tsearch: {
                          any_word: true
                      }
                  }


  has_many :variations, -> { order(:order) }, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

**variation.rb**

```
class Variation < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :products
  ...
end
```

**products_controller.rb**
*Its the @total_items below I can't figure out how to make a part of the (params[:query])*

```
...
def index
      if params[:query]
        @products = Product.search_for(params[:query])
        @total_collections = Product.search_for(params[:query]).count
        @total_items = Variation.joins(:product).count
      else
        ...
      end
end
...
```

Comment: Try using `Variation.joins(:product).where(products: @products).count`

Comment: @MrYoshiji I changed `.where(:products: @products)` to `.where(:product: @products)` and it worked.  Thank you.

Comment: is your DB table for the model `Product` named `product`? (and not `products`, plural)

Comment: no, its plural, but its probably because of the `belongs_to :product` in my  variation model...  I probably need to do some refactoring